# How get rid of the Action Name in URL after MVC Form Post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a reset password method that I am posting to it in MVC. when I click on Submit button and page posted the URL would be like: http://localhost:11580/resetpassword
so it will bring the name of the action method in URL, that is why the link in page is not working anymore, can I can get rid of the resetpassword action name?

The link I am referring to is this link that is in My Index page:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password", "forgotPassword", new { controller = "Home" } , new { id = "btn-forgot-password"})
```

As all this code are in Modal that is over the Index page.

I am using MVC form post, this is my methods:

```
       [HttpGet]
       [Route("resetpassword")]
       [AllowAnonymous]
       public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordRequest resetPasswordRequest)
          {
            .....
                        return View("ForgotPasswordError");
                }
                else
                {
                  .......
                    return View("Index", logInRequest);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
        return View("Index", logInRequest);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("resetpassword")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel resetPasswordViewModel)
    {
        ....
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ......
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Please enter the same value    again.");
                  return View(resetPasswordViewModel);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Password is Required Field.");
            return View(resetPasswordViewModel);
        }
        LogInRequest logInRequest = new LogInRequest();
        logInRequest.IsThankYouPage = true;
        return View("Index", logInRequest);
    }
```

And this is the View that is posting:

```
  @model Models.LogInRequest
   <link href="~/Content/Styles/ModalStyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="~/Content/Styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
   @{
   Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterLayout.cshtml";
    }
   @if (Model != null && Model.IsResetPassword)
  {
  <div class="page resetPassword">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("resetpassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="close">X</span>
                <h2 id="modal-title">Reset Your Garage Password</h2>
                <hr />
                <div>
                    <div class="create-user-label">Email Address</div>
                    <div><input type="email" name="Email"   placeholder="jdoe@example.com" class="create-new-password-textbox-grey" readonly value=@Model.UserName /></div>
                    <div class="create-user-label">Password</div>
                    <div><input type="Password" id="Password" name="Password" placeholder="Create Password" class="create-new-password-textbox" onblur="validatePassword();" /></div>
                    <div id="resetPassword-default-message" class="resetPassword-default-message">Password must be at least 8 characters.</div>
                    <div id="resetpassword-message"><label class="resetpassword-error" id="password-error"></label> </div>
                    <div class="create-user-label">Confirm Password</div>
                    <div><input type="Password" name="ConfirmPassword" id="ConfirmPassword" placeholder="Re-enter Password" class="create-new-password-textbox" onblur="validateConfirmPassword();" /></div>
                    <div id="confirmPassword-message"><label class="resetpassword-error" id="confirmPassword-error"></label> </div>
                    <br />
                    <div>
                        <input type="submit" id="btnSubmit" value="Submit" class="orange-button create-password-button-half" onclick="validatePasswordSubmit();" />
                        <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Token" name="token" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
   }
  @if(Model.IsThankYouPage)
  {
<div id="ThankYou-Page" class="modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="close">x</div>
    <div id="reset">
        <div class="modal-heading">Success!</div>
        <hr class="forgot-password-line" />
        <br />
        <p>Your password has been successfully reset. Please sign in.</p>
        <br />
    </div>
</div>
 </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  renderThankYouPage();
  </script>
 }
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/User/CreatePassword.js"></script>
```

Comment: What 'link' are you referring to? (your question is not making sense)

Answer (score 0):

That's the URL to which the form was posted, and since the response from the server is a view then that's what the user sees.

Instead of returning a view, redirect the user to the action you want.  So instead of this:

```
return View("Index", logInRequest);
```

Something like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

I guess the real question here is, what is `logInRequest` and why does the index view need that?  Ideally what you should be doing here is a redirect, and there really shouldn't be any data to pass along.  The user has reset their password, they should simply be able to proceed.

Comment: the link is working now but as I need to send a model to like    return RedirectToAction("Index", logInRequest); not the URL is looks like: http://localhost:11580/IsResetPassword=False&IsThankYouPage=True&IsCreatePassword=False&IsCreatePasswordThankYouPage=False

Comment: @nakisa: A redirect only returns a header telling the browser to perform a GET request.  It's very limited in what you can send it.  *Why* does the index action need this model?  Are users normally entirely unable to navigate to the index page without it?  I suspect you've made a design mistake somewhere.

Comment: you are probably right about the design mistake, I send some value to Index view to show/hide part of it.

Comment: @nakisa: If all you need is a flag to indicate some boolean value to the index view, `TempData` may be a good place for that.